# selecting a distinct value based on 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables, which are joined by a left join.

Table1:

- Id (int)
- Name (string)

Table2:

- Id (int)
- Table1Id (int)
- Allowed (bit)

Based on the name saved in table one, I can get all records in table 2. When one or more records in table 2 have the value of allowed = 0 the result of my query should return 0. I tried using min(), but it doesn't support bit values, i tried converting them to integer values but that doesn't seem to work either. how exactly would I do this?

To clarify, I want to see all records that exist. Only when one of the records in table 2 has a value of 0 (for allowed), then the result of the query should display 0 as well

Something like this would do the trick, but I don't know which aggregate function to use, so I could group buy the Table1.Name

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table2.Allowed  
FROM Table1  
LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id  
GROUP BY Table1.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Table1.Name, min(case when Table2.Allowed = 0 then 0 else 1 end)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id
GROUP BY Table1.Name
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22197/1)

Comment: hi Juergen, thank you for your answer, however, i also went to display the records where the sum would be 1. so to clarify, record 1 has 2 records in table 2, one with 0 and one with 1. the result should be 0. only when there are no 0's in table 2, the result might be 1. if no record exist in table 2, the result should be 1 as well

Comment: Yes, your's works, only not this revision, min() does not take bit values in SSMS

Comment: So you are now using SQL Server?

Comment: yes, i noticed that that i clicked the wrong tag, and we are using sql server 2012, i added that tag as well

Answer (score 0):

While the question might not have been clear, I have found a second solution to my problem:

```
SELECT [Name] AS [Name], MIN(Allowed)   
FROM(

SELECT [Table1].[Name] AS [Name],   
CAST(ISNULL([Table2].[Allowed], 1) as int) AS [allowed]  
FROM [Table1] AS [T1]  
LEFT JOIN [Table2] AS [T2] on [T1].[Id] = [T2].[Table1Id]  
) AS [Records]  

GROUP BY [Name]
```

When running in SSMS, looking at the execution plan, there are no differences with Juergen's answer. The query cost is 50% each, and the graphical paths are identical

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is to use a subquery, you can save your cpu from that agregation workload.

select t1.name, 0 as allowed
from table1 t1
where t1.id in (select t2.table1id from table2 t2 where t2.allowed = 0)